# topological equivalence on interior of $D^2$ that is not continously extendable to $D^2$

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification

As said in the title, I'm trying to find a topological equivalence on the interior of $D^2$ that is not continously extendable to $D^2$. I have an idea about this, so here it goes:

Let $id_{int(D^2)}:(int(D^2),T_1)\to (int(D^2),T_2)$ be the identity on the interior of $D^2$, where $T_2$ is a topology, with its open sets defined as $\{(x,y)\in int(D^2):\exists\epsilon\ge0:B_\epsilon(x,y)\subseteq int(D^2)\}$ ($B_\epsilon(x,y)$is the epsilon ball around $(x,y)$ with respect to the standard metric on $\mathbb{R}^2$). It is clear that $T_2$ defines a topology. $T_1$ is the discrete topology, that is every set is open. The identity is obviously continuous and bijective and the inverse is continuous too, since every open set in $T_1$ has an open set as its image (because we can find a ball around each point).

But if we extend this to the identity on $D^2$, the image of for example $(1,0)$, which is $(1,0)$, is not open anymore, since there is no epsilon for which the ball around $(1,0)$ will be in $D^2$.

Since I'm new to topology I wanted to know if there is any holes in this proof.

Comment: So $T_1$ is the discrete topology, and $T_2$ the standard topology. But then the identity is not continuous from $(\operatorname{int}(D^2),T_2)$ to $(\operatorname{int}(D^2),T_1)$.

Comment: No, $T_2$ is not the standard topology. A set is open in $T_2$ if we can find an epsilon ball in $int(D^2)$ that contains it. And since we can find a ball around any set in $(int(D^2),T_2)$, every pre-image is open.

Comment: He's saying that it's not a homeomorphism because the inverse $\operatorname{id}: (\operatorname{int}(D^2),T_2) \to (\operatorname{int}(D^2),T_1)$ isn't continuous.

Comment: Well, it is entirely unclear to me what $T_2$ is supposed to be then. Anyway, if you want to talk about extending a map to $D^2$ and the continuity of that, you need topologies on $D^2$, not only $\operatorname{int}(D^2)$.

Comment: Oh. And after your latest edit which states that the basic open sets of $T_2$ are of the form $\{p \in \operatorname{int}(D^2) \mid \exists \epsilon {\color{red}\geq} 0 : B_\epsilon(p) \subseteq \operatorname{int}(D^2)\}$, $T_2$ is just the discrete topology which is probably not what you meant. And if you write "$>$" instead, it's the standard topology.

Comment: I see that now, too. I don't have an idea then on for which homeomorphism the extension will fail. Do you have any hints?

Comment: Imagine the unit disk were a red rubber disk, with a couple of radii marked with blue lines, fixed rigidly at the origin. Grab the rim and pull. The rubber disk starts to twist and the blue lines bend. Pull stronger and the blue lines bend more. Make a small leap of faith and imagine you've twisted the rubber disk so far that the ex-radii now are spirals winding a complete turn around the origin. Pull stronger and stronger. Make a big leap of faith and imagine the radii have become spirals winding infinitely often around the origin.

Comment: I think that helped. So basically if we have polar coordinates $r,\phi$ we look at $f(r,\phi)=(r,\phi+r/(1-r))$. This is a homeomorphism but extending it to the boundary breaks continuity, since the pre-image of every boundary point is arbitrarily close to every boundary point.

Comment: Wow! That was way faster than I expected.

Comment: I had three hours to think about it more :) Your comment just helped me find the last step.

Comment: How much of it had you already found before my comment?

Comment: I was thinking of deformations of the disk, I just didn't twist it often enough.